# unable to push into my github repository (The requested URL returned error: 403)

Tags: git, github, repository, push

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/shaurya2412/practice.git

saxen@LAPTOP-E6U7B2OT MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder (2) (master)
$ git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/shaurya2412/practice.git'

saxen@LAPTOP-E6U7B2OT MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder (2) (master)
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to shaurya2412/practice.git denied to ShaURYA123CODER.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/shaurya2412/practice.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

saxen@LAPTOP-E6U7B2OT MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder (2) (master)
$ git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true

saxen@LAPTOP-E6U7B2OT MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder (2) (main)
$ git remote set-url origin https://shaurya2412@github.com/user/practice.git

I tried the online solution i thought could work out but could not find a solution to my problem i was unable to push my code in the repository i expect a reason to my problem and way to solve that too.
thank you

Comment: `git push -u origin master` looks fine with the HTTPs URL - except that you seem to be logged in with the wrong user.

Answer (score 0):

Because configuration URL have a backslash in the end and you should reset URL

You can change URL manually first go to your project and open your terminal here and  opening .git/config with any editor

```
notepad .git/config
```

And change URL:

```bash
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/shaurya2412/practice.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Save changes and close Notepad, Now you can push to remote server:

```
git push origin master
```

And push again it will push without any problem.